# Select option not to href but to #id

Tags: php, jquery

I have a select box, and the option values are built like.

```
<option value="#/page/<?=$count;?>" id="selector-page-<?=$count;?>">Page <?=$count-1;?> to <?=$count;?></option>
```

On selection of the option need to append the #/page value to the url, without page refresh.

Works perfect on a href but cannot get it to append via option select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a function to whenever the select changes, the value will be updated, and you can set that as the location hash :

```
$('#your_select_id').on('change', function() {
    window.location.hash = this.value;
});
```

Comment: Worked perfect first time thanks, will select as best answer when i can.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `window.location.hash = '#/page';` when the option is clicked?

Give a  CSS `class` or `id` to your `select` and then you could do something like this:

```
$('select#YOUR_SELECT_ID').change(function(){
   window.location.hash = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/X9L6Y/1/show/)

```
$("#selectId").on('change',function(){
  window.location.hash = $(this).val();
});
```